# BootstrapValidator not showing success message

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

**Edit**: *The original codepen I borrowed this from is [here](http://codepen.io/jaycbrf/pen/iBszr). The only difference is in the HTML I changed the `action=' '` (it was blank, all php code was in the same file as the form) to `action='mail-form.php'`.  Is this why the javascript isn't working?*

I'm using bootstrapvalidator for validation on my php form.  It works great but when I submit the form, instead of showing my success notification it is going to the form's `action` page.  The form works and the email is sent.

Here is my form declaration:

```
<form class="well form-horizontal" action="mail-form.php" method="post"  id="contact_form">
```

Here is the bootstrap validator's call to submit the form in my javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
        // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        // Removed validation rules for brevity //
       .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
            $('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow") // Do something ...
                $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the form instance
            var $form = $(e.target);

            // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
            var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

            // Use Ajax to submit form data
            $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }, 'json');
        });
});
```

When I submit the form after validation is successful, it directs me to the form's `action` which is `mail-form.php`.  I was expecting it to just show the `#success-message` div as stated above in the javascript, but it does not.  Just opens `mail-form.php` which is a blank page that echoes out the fields values that were submitted (for my debugging).

If it helps, here's where I'm adding my script files in my pages footer.

```
  ...
  </footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "contact.php") { ?>
      <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    <?php } ?>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

I was always told any script declarations needed to be at the end of the file so they get loaded right before the page is completely loaded. I don't know if this is a reason for the problem I'm having (I'm very new to jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this submit event to prevent the form from submitting on click

```
$('#contact_form').on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
```

or use the function:

```
submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {}
```

see:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MadxaE?editors=001

Comment: I just append this to the end of my script file?   Or does this replace anything?  Or does it go in the `//Do Something` comment?

Comment: That's what it looks like now, but I have the exact same behavior as originally stated.  I made this codepen to make it more readable (javascript only) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVyKgX

Comment: put it outside the on success.form.bv event

Comment: I did that and now the form doesn't submit.  I added an alert and for some reason the PREVENT ALERT triggers twice.  I think the problem is that the `.on('success.form.bv', function(e) {` isn't firing.  I added an alert immediately before the success message was suppose to be shown but it never fires.  http://codepen.io/drpcken/pen/OyYwLV?editors=001

Comment: PERFECT!  Thank you!!  I really need to study jquery more in order to understand why that didn't work.  Like I don't know what the .on('success.form.bv) was trying to select and use.  Regardless it works now.  Thank you!!

Comment: Hi Madalin! I'm using the code that you kindly provided but it seems that that for bootstrap validator version > 0.5 we need to replace submitHandler by success.form.bv Any chance for you to adapt your code? Many thanks!